# Add a column containing node degrees of a network to a dataframe

Tags: r, igraph, degrees

I have information on physicians working in different hospitals at different points in time. I would like to define networks at the hospital-period level so that peers are physicians who work together in the same hospital at the same time.

I would like, then, to compute node degrees by month. My final output should be a dataframe informing the degrees by node-period. It should include zero degrees for isolated nodes.

Consider the very simple example of hospitals x-y-w-z, periods 1-2 and physicians A-B-C-D-E.

```
mydf <- data.frame(hospital = c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","w","w","w","w","z"), 
               period = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2), 
               id = c("A","B","C","A","B","A","A","C","C","D","A","D","E"))
```

The code below construct a dataframe with all pairs of connected physicians by hospital-period.

```
relations <- mydf %>%
  left_join(mydf, by=c("hospital","period")) %>%
  filter(id.y!=id.x) %>%
  relocate(id.y,id.x)
```

The code below informs the node degreess of each connected node by period.

```
relations %>%
  group_by(period) %>%
  group_map(~ degree(simplify(graph_from_data_frame(.x, directed = FALSE))))
```

The dataframe below is my desired output. Note that it includes node `E` at `period 2` with zero degree.

```
output <- data.frame(node=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","E"),
                     period=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                     degree=c(2,2,3,1,3,1,1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
mydf %>%
  arrange(period) %>%
  select(-hospital) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(period) %>%
  left_join(
    relations %>%
      group_by(period) %>%
      do(
        setNames(
          stack(degree(simplify(graph_from_data_frame(., directed = FALSE)))),
          c("degrees", "id")
        )
      )
  ) %>%
  mutate(degrees = replace_na(degrees, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
  period id    degrees
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1      1 A           2
2      1 B           2
3      1 C           3
4      1 D           1
5      2 A           3
6      2 B           1
7      2 C           1
8      2 D           1
9      2 E           0
```

Comment: Very clever solution. Could you provide the explanation on the machanism of `do(setNames(stack(...)))`  code chunk please?

Comment: @PeteKittinun `degree` returns named vector. If we apply `stack` over the named vector, we will get a data frame with two columns, i.e., names and values. That will be the information you need since you want to retain both the degree values as well as node name (names of vertices).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your relations map contain every information needed.

```
lists <- relations %>%
  group_by(period) %>%
  group_map(~ degree(simplify(graph_from_data_frame(.x, directed = FALSE))))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

node_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lists)) %>% mutate(period = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !period, names_to = "nodes", values_to = "degree") %>% arrange(period, nodes) %>% 
  relocate(period, .after = nodes)

  nodes period degree
  <chr>  <int>  <dbl>
1 A          1      2
2 B          1      2
3 C          1      3
4 D          1      1
5 A          2      1
6 B          2      1
7 C          2      3
8 D          2      1
```

However this solution is not perfect since E=0 was not included. You may have to tweak your first code a bit to also display them. (I know nothing about igraph library)

Comment: There is an issue with `data.frame(do.call(rbind, lists))` as the nodes in each list are not in the same order. It may also be the case that some nodes only show up in a few periods. Could we take this into account in the code?

Comment: Sorry but I am not quite clear about "each list are not in the same order".

Comment: May be arrange 'period' before using group_map()?